# How to electronize a UNO Wasm application

Tags: c#, xaml, webassembly, uno-platform, winui

How can we run a Uno Wasm project through an Electron shell?

The official way of electronizing blazor doesn't work in uno, because there uno wasm runs abit differently (there is no Hosting to inject electron .net) and simply putting "published" uno wasm content in "electron-quickstart" project won't let the uno wasm app run correctly.

Is there any correct way of running a uno-wasm project through an Electron window?

Answer (score -1):

The only (dating) existing sample [is this one](https://github.com/unoplatform/Uno.Wasm.Bootstrap/tree/6919f41e62c506d7b6f7742d055a298bb5515613/src/Uno.Wasm.Tests.Electron).

The sample works by bundling the Uno Platform `dist` folder, and adding a bootstrapping electron file which opens `index.html`.

Comment: Using that method isn't working.
It logs "require" related errors like

`Uncaught Error: Module name "package_f2d7b23c9b7a894ff23d0d28e5422d254b663141/WasmWebSockets" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])`